# Enable interaction with NSWindow when sheet is opened

Tags: cocoa, button, nswindow

I'm creating an app that calls a sheet, however, the interaction with the window must stay enabled while the sheet is open. Here's a mock-up:

[image: http://twitpic.com/3k382o]

The user must be able to use the play and record buttons. Does anyone knows a way to keep it enabled?

Comment: You can add your image directly to this question rather than posting it on another site.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a slightly questionable UI. But if you really want to do it, think the only solution will be to either:

- Subclass NSWindow to force handling of the events
- Run the event loop for that window while the sheet is visible, and dispatch desired events yourself

Answer (score 0):

Sheets are intentionally designed to block interaction with the window they're attached to.  If you don't want that behavior, you shouldn't be using a sheet.